MassTransit RabbitMQ creates unnecessary exchange for the consumer even after giving ConfigureConsumeTopology = false
Here is my configuration for a consumer using MassTransit
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
        {                
            config.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                var hostUri = new Uri("amqp://localhost/)";
                cfg.Host(hostUri, configurator =>
                {                         
                    configurator.Username("guest");
                    configurator.Password("guest");
                });

                
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("testQ", cfx =>
                {                        
                    cfx.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    cfx.Consumer<TestConsumer>();
                    cfx.Bind("test-exchange", x => {
                        x.RoutingKey = "test1";
                        x.ExchangeType = "direct";
                    });
                    configurator.ExchangeType = "direct";
                });
            });
          })

This consumer configuration creates exchanges with name testQ and test-exchange. How can I change this to only create test-exchange bound to the testQ?
